# Joining 2 tables- in Select statement show how many fields matched directly (A1 = B1), vs matched on isnull(A1,B1) = B1

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables which I need to join, 
but sometimes there are

1) direct joins e.g. `t1.FieldA = t2.FieldA`

OR

2) when `t2.FieldA` is `null` then it must join as well then `t2.FieldA` is null `t1.FieldA = isnull(t2.FieldA,t1.fieldA)`

BUT

I have to keep track of how many were direct `joins`, how many were `isnull joins`, since there are precedent levels which need to be calculated, e.g. even though the items
joined the one where there are 5 direct joins are higher than when it joined on 5 `isnull` values

Now it is a hell of a mission to have the following in the `Select` statement, since there can be more than 5 fields to compare.

e.g. I need to test

1. Does all 5 match?
2. Does `A, B, C, D`  match? then 4
3. Does `A, B, D, E`  match? then 4
4. Does `A, B, C, E`  match? then 4

etc.

This is way to sloppy, I am looking for help on method to count how many were directly joined please

```
case when t1.A = t2.A and t1.B = t2.B and t1.C = t2.C and t1.D = t2.D  and t1.E = t2.E  then  5 
     when t1.A = t2.A and t1.B = t2.B and t1.C = t2.C and t1.D = t2.D                 then  4
     when t1.B = t2.B and t1.C = t2.C and t1.D = t2.D and t1.E = t2.E                 then  4
     when t1.A = t2.A and t1.E = t2.E                 then 2
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4af9/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about :

```
CASE WHEN t2.A IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN t2.B IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN t2.C IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN t2.D IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN t2.E IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```